# How to use Action with unknown number of Parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates, action, parameter-passing

Hi i would like to do something like:

```
public class Subscription
{    
    private Action _action;        //????

    public Subscription( Action a )//????
    {
        _action = a;               //????
    }
}


public class testklass
{        
     public testklass()
     {
         new Subscription(a); // just to show you how i want to submit
         new Subscription(b);
         new Subscription(c);
     } 

     private void a() { }
     private void b(string gg){}
     private void c(int i, string g) { } 
}
```

Is there a way to do this? 
And will it cost much performance?

Any advice is greatly appreciated

### EDIT:

**i going to bild a Mediator**

`testklass` is just a subscriber who create a `Subscription` Object and Hand it over to the `Mediator` 
who does the logic behind all this when a other Class publish a Object/s that match the subscribtion

but at the moment only want to now how to store a `Action` with unknown number of Parameters in my Container Object `Subscription`

Comment: How do you expect `Subscription` to call a two-argument action vs. a no-argument action?

Comment: Agree with @dasblinkenlight how are you going to invoke different actions and pass different number of parameters?

Comment: it's just a Contain class it wont call anything i only want to store it as a Action and a other Class will get this Action an check what Parameters are needed to execute it

Comment: @WiiMaxx Since you are not planning to use the `Action` as an action, just as a storage, you might as well store it as an `object`.

Comment: @WiiMaxx You almost certainly don't want to be doing that.  It will make your code a mess.  Since we don't know what problem you're trying to solve with this approach I couldn't suggest a more proper way though.

Comment: @ Servy see my Edit. Ihope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Subscription<T>
    {
        private T _action;       

        public Subscription(T a)
        {
            _action = a;        
        }
    }
```

you can use it like;

```
Action<int> func1 = (q) => q += 1;
Action<int,int> func2 = (q,w) => q += w;
Subscription<Action<int>> s1 = new Subscription<Action<int>>(func1);
Subscription<Action<int,int>> s2 = new Subscription<Action<int,int>>(func2);
```

As a side note, I do not know what you are trying to do but there may be a better way of doing it.

Comment: really nice i can also  use it like; `new Subscription<Action>(a); new Subscription<Action<string>>(b); new Subscription<Action<int,string>>(c);`

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class testklass
    {
        public testklass()
        {
            new Subscription(a); // just to show you how i want to submit
            new Subscription(() => b("someparam"));
            new Subscription(()=>c(10, "someparam"));
        }

        private void a() { }
        private void b(string gg) { }
        private void c(int i, string g) { }
    }
```

Comment: Actually you are passing simple `Action` with captured parameters. Subscription cannot call action with new parameters

Answer (score 0):

you could make your function get in determinant count of various params within the following syntax

> resultType functionName(params object[] list) {...}

And then using that function with any count of parameters you want.

Also you could implement function parameters like an array or list or object. Then your function will take only one argument - the object which store your params.

So, as you can see there are a plenty of ways to do that.